# Exception "Unable to insert a line" TComboBox with CharCase ecLowerCase or ecUpperCase

Tags: delphi, tcombobox

In **Delphi 10.3.2**, when I programmatically insert items in a TComboBox having "CharCase = ecLowerCase" (or ecUpperCase), I get the error
**Project XXXX raise exception class EOutOfResources with message 'Unable to insert a line'** 
The error only appears when I add to my project the unit **SHAREMEM** (I need to reference that unit as I have to exchange dynamic strings with a DLL).
It seems that the error is related to this remark I found in the procedure TComboBoxStrings.Add() (unit StdCtrls.pas): ***From the Windows SDK documentation: Comclt32.dll version 5.0 or later: If CBS_LOWERCASE or CBS_UPPERCASE is set, the Unicode version of CB_ADDSTRING alters the string. If using read-only global memory, this causes the application to fail.***

```
program combo_lowercase;

uses ShareMem,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

---

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses Forms, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
     combo: TComboBox;
     procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    combo.Items.Clear;
    combo.Items.Add('AAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
    combo.Items.Add('bbbbbbbbbbbbbb');
    combo.Items.Add('CCCCCccccccccc');
    combo.Items.Add('ddddddDDDDDDDD');
end;

end.
```

---

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 206
  ClientWidth = 496
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object combo: TComboBox
     Left = 48
     Top = 20
     Width = 145
     Height = 21
     Style = csDropDownList
     CharCase = ecLowerCase
     TabOrder = 0
  end
end
```

Is there a workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior in a brand new project? Note that you'll get the error if your index is greater than the count of items or less than -1, in any Delphi version.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I created a new project with only a 'lowercase' combo, I tried to fill it with items and I got no errors. Than I found this remark in the procedure TComboBoxString.Add() (StdCtrls unit): " _From the Windows SDK documentation: Comclt32.dll version 5.0 or later: If CBS_LOWERCASE or CBS_UPPERCASE is set, the Unicode version of CB_ADDSTRING alters the string. If using read-only global memory, this causes the application to fail._ ". I tried to add the unit *SHAREMEM* in the uses clauses of my application, and I got the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: VCL calls UniqueString so there should be no problem with the API modifying the string.

Comment: The comment you include from the VCL source has zero to do with needing to add Sharemem, so remove it.  It has nothing to do with anything related to that comment at all. You're also expecting us to debug code we cannot see. If the issue does not appear with a new empty project, then the problem is in your code, which we cannot see until you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @KenWhite I need to use Sharemem as I have to call a DLL from my application.
If I create a new project without Sharemem, the problem does not appear. If I use Sharemem, the problem appears

Comment: You don't need ShareMem in your app; just in the DLL

Comment: We need to see that [mcve]

Comment: @DaveNottage If i don't use ShareMem both in DLL and application, I get protection errors.
Furthermore, in Embarcadero documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Sharing_Memory you can read:
**List ShareMem as the first unit in the program and library uses clause.**
And however, same issue would be present in DLL

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I included a minimal reproducible example in the question. Isn't it enough?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't appear to lead to the behaviour that you describe. Did you try it yourself? If I had to guess I'd suppose that your borlndmm.dll is not the right version. Take the version from the bin directory of your Delphi installation and put it in the same directory as your exe file.

Comment: I don't have 10.3.2 installed, so I tried your code in XE7, and there was no problems. If you trace into `function TComboBoxStrings.Add(const S: string): Integer;` what is the value of `Result` immediately after `  Result := SendMessage(ComboBox.Handle, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPStr);`

Comment: Bravo @DavidHeffernan, and **many thanks** to all of you !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you show does not lead to the error that you report. The only explanation I can come up with to account for the significance of `Sharemem` is that its use leads to an erroneous version of borlandmm.dll being loaded. Make sure that your process loads the correct version of that DLL. Copy it from the bin directory to the same directory as your executable.

Comment: Many many thanks, David.
**The problem actually was a copy of the D6 version of borlndmm.dll in the SysWOW64 directory.**
The strange thing is that this is (apparently) the only problem determined by the wrong DLL version. I have almost finished the porting of a 1-million-lines application (from D6 to DX 10, with DLLs), and honestly I would have thought that for such a gross error everything would be blocked, while everything seems to work (enough :-)) correctly.
**Thanks again**